# Is there a style to print crochet patterns

Tags: fonts, packages

I think I have seen a style file, to print crochet patterns within LaTeX, but I can't find it any more.

Crochet patterns are a visual description on how to knot your yarn.  Something like [this example](https://www.crazypatterns.net/de/blog/956/haekelschrift-kein-problem-haekeln-lernen-teil-1).

Comment: You can do that in Ti*k*Z, with the use of `pic`.

Comment: @SebGlav I am sure, there are more than one solution.  But my intention was to use a predefined style, instead of defining every minipic by myself.

Comment: The [knitting](https://ctan.org/pkg/knitting) package, by the looks of it?